# Makefile: How to expand a variable in a shell function correctly?

Tags: shell, makefile

I have a reoccurring piece of code in my makefile, which I want to put in a function. A simplified version of my code looks as follows:

```
IDS=4 5
MY_FUNC = $(shell echo "max=2; \
        counter=1;\
        while [ \$$counter -le \$$max ]; do\
            id=$$(echo $(IDS) | cut -d" " -f \$${counter}); \
            counter=\$$((counter+1)); \
        done");

.PHONY: all
all: 
    @$(call MY_FUNC)
```

Unfortunately, `cut` interprets $counter literally and consequently throws the error message `cut: invalid field value ‘$counter’`.

I do not understand why this is the case, since the command `\$$command` accesses the value stored inside this variable. Do you may know how to properly call pass `counter` to `cut`?

Comment: you don't use \$$ for echo $(IDS) so why for cut?

Comment: `IDS` is a make variable, which is why you access it with a single $. However, `counter` is a shell variable. You can echo `counter` with `echo \$$counter;` successfully.

Comment: but you use it inside command substitution $(...) is that still necessary then?

Comment: Yes, I guess so :). If you take the code of `MY_FUNC` directly as the recipe of `all`, it works perfectly fine (you then of course need to replace `\$$` with `$$`). And in addition `cut` tells me that there is an issue with `counter`, not with `IDS`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a fixed form of your `Makefile`.

```
IDS=4 5
MY_FUNC = $(shell echo 'max=2; \
        counter=1; \
        while [ $$counter -le $$max ]; do\
            id=$$(echo $(IDS) | cut -d" " -f $${counter}); \
            counter=$$((counter+1)); \
        echo "debug: id: $$id"; \
        done');

.PHONY: all
all: 
    @$(call MY_FUNC)
```

I have added a `echo "debug: id: $$id";` command to help with debugging and prove that the script is behaving as intended. Here is the output:

```
$ make
debug: id: 4
debug: id: 5
```

Here are the important points worth noting in the fixed script:

- The outermost delimiter for the argument to the outermost `echo` statement is single-quote (not double-quotes) in order to prevent the `$counter`, `$max`, etc. from expanding to empty strings when the `echo` statement is being executed by the `$(shell echo ...)` call from `Makefile`. This also allows proper nesting of the double-quotes used in `cut -d" "` within the outer single-quotes.
- Now that we are using single-quotes as the outer delimiters, the `$` symbols within (escaped as `$$` in `Makefile`) need not be escaped with `\` anymore.

If however you want to stick with double-quotes as the outermost delimiter, then the alternative solution with minimal changes to your code looks like this:

```
IDS=4 5
MY_FUNC = $(shell echo "max=2; \
        counter=1;\
        while [ \$$counter -le \$$max ]; do\
            id=\$$(echo $(IDS) | cut -d\" \" -f \$${counter}); \
            counter=\$$((counter+1)); \
            echo \"debug: id: \$$id\"; \
        done");

.PHONY: all
all: 
    @$(call MY_FUNC)
```

Once again the output is:

```
$ make
debug: id: 4
debug: id: 5
```

Here are the important points to note in this alternative solution:

- All `$` symbols for the shell (escaped as `$$` in `Makefile`) need to be escaped carefully. They should all occur as `\$$` in `Makefile`. In your code, this was missing for `$$(echo`. This has been fixed to `\$$(echo`.
- Further all double-quotes within the outer double-quotes need to be carefully escaped as `\"`, so `cut -d" "` should be written as `cut -d\" \"`.

Comment: Perfect. This is what I was looking for. Thank you. So basically, I forgot to escape the `$$(echo)` properly. I gonna use the single quoted expression to avoid the pain of escaping.

Answer (score 1):

[Susam Pal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/303363/susam-pal)'s answer explains why your use of double quotes was wrong. Use one or the other of the two proposed solutions.

And then, there are a few other aspects you could consider:

1. You are using the `$(shell...)` make function in a recipe which does not realy make sense: recipes are already shell scripts. And you do not need the `call` function neither. A simpler Makefile could be:

   ```
    IDS = 4 5

    define MY_FUNC
    max=2; \
    counter=1; \
    while [ $$counter -le $$max ]; do \
      id=$$(echo $(IDS) | cut -d" " -f $${counter}); \
      counter=$$((counter+1)); \
    done
    endef

    .PHONY: all

    all: 
        @$(MY_FUNC)
   ```
2. As your recipe has no side effect it is not very useful. But I guess you know it already and this was just an example.
3. Hard-wiring the number of items in `IDS` (`max=2`) in your recipe is not optimal. If you are using GNU make you could use its `words` function:

   ```
    max=$(words $(IDS)); \
   ```
4. There are much simpler ways to achieve what you want with the shell. Assuming you just want to print the id values:

   ```
    for id in $(IDS); do; \
      echo $$id; \
    done
   ```

   is easier. But I guess you know it already and this was just an example.
5. If you want to use the `call` function you could pass it a parameter (the current id) and iterate with the `foreach` make function instead of using a shell loop:

   ```
    IDS = 4 5

    define MY_FUNC
    echo $(1)

    endef

    .PHONY: all

    all:
        $(foreach id,$(IDS),@$(call MY_FUNC,$(id)))
   ```

   Note the empty last line of `MY_FUNC`. It is needed to obtain a true multi-line recipe. Alternate solution with a single-line recipe:

   ```
    IDS = 4 5

    MY_FUNC = echo $(1)

    .PHONY: all

    all:
        @$(foreach id,$(IDS),$(call MY_FUNC,$(id));)
   ```
6. GNU make offers many handy functions and has many very useful features. In your case (and assuming you just want to print each `id` on standard output) you could use `patsubst` to create a list of phony targets, one per word in `IDS` and write a static pattern rule for all of them:

   ```
    IDS  = 4 5
    ALLS = $(patsubst %,all-%,$(IDS))

    .PHONY: all $(ALLS)

    all: $(ALLS)

    $(ALLS): all-%:
        @echo $*
   ```

   An advantage of this last solution is that your ids are distributed to as many independent rules (the `all-X`) and their recipes can be run in parallel by make if you allow it to do so (`make -j`) while with single rule solutions they necessarily run sequentially.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Yes, you convinced me to use the define environment, since the `shell` inside a recipe is indeed not necessary. 

I am aware of the potential for code optimizations, specifically when it comes to the in-built functions of make. `MY_FUNC`, however, is more complex, which is why I broke it down to the above code to illustrate my problem.